# Potential synonym between [autopilot] and [autonomous] tags?

Tags: discussion

I realise that the differences between 'autopilot' and 'autonomous' are comparable to a car having 'cruise control' or 'self-driving' capabilities, but I feel the distinctions aren't made clear in the tag descriptions:

> **Questions tagged [autopilot](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autopilot)**
>
> Any software system that allows a UAV to fly fully autonomously.
>
> **Questions tagged [autonomous](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autonomous)**
>
> Something that guides or controls all or part of its own functions.

I feel that these tags, given their descriptions, are used more or less interchangeably and should either:

- Be modified to make them distinct from each other
- Be merged together as synonyms

What are your thoughts on this matter?

Answer (score 3):

I think there is an important but small difference; although I think we are slightly comparing apples to pears. I would use the following, but I haven't checked whether the questions we have are using the terms in this way:

- An **autonomous** aircraft can operate completely independently of a remote pilot - such as able to make its own collision avoidance decisions.
- An **automatic** aircraft is controlled by a computer or other machine without a human. It follows the flight which it was programmed to fly.
- An **autopilot** is a system which facilitates one of the above.

*(I'm fairly sure I first heard the autonomous/automatic distinction from the UK CAA, but I can't find where at the moment so perhaps I've made that up!)*

Comment: Define "operate independently". This can have any level of meaning we wish, it all depends on the task at hand.

Comment: Were you thinking of [CAP 722](https://publicapps.caa.co.uk/docs/33/CAP722_Edition7_A3_SEP2019_20190903.pdf), perhaps?

Comment: Good find - CAP722 definitely says what I was thinking of; not sure that's where I first read it (I think an email or ORS document?) but it reassures me that I haven't made it up!